# Oracle : YEAR Keyword invalid

Tags: sql, oracle

I have dates stored in the price_date column in one of my oracle tables. I need to filter records that belong to the year 2014 for e.g

```
select * from MIS_PERMAL.MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE 
where index_id = 1045 and YEAR(PRICE_DATE) = 2014
```

I am getting error saying YEAR is invalid.

Comment: So look up this alleged YEAR function in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have a `year()` function. You seem to have got that syntax from a different database ([like MySQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)).

You can use [the `extract()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html) instead:

```
select * from MIS_PERMAL.MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE
where index_id = 1045
and EXTRACT(YEAR from PRICE_DATE) = 2014
```

Comment: Funny you mention it +1, because I actually thought Oracle did have a `YEAR` function.  Probably confusion from using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I up-voted Alex's answer, here is another method:

```
select * from MIS_PERMAL.MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE 
where index_id = 1045 and trunc(PRICE_DATE, 'YYYY') = date '2014-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an index on the `price_date` column then you can to select on a range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MIS_PERMAL.MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE 
WHERE  index_id = 1045
AND    price_date >= DATE '2014-01-01'
AND    price_date <  DATE '2015-01-01'
```

---

If you compare using `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM price_date) = 2014` or `TRUNC(price_date) = DATE '2014-01-01'` then Oracle will not use a
index on the `price_date` column (and you would need a function-based index on `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM price_date)` or `TRUNC(price_date)` instead).